# What method and the libraries in C++ are most suitable and easy to create a (server) back-end for web?

Tags: c++, web-services, cgi, fastcgi

What method and the libraries in C++ are most suitable and easy to create a (server) back-end for web?
What do you advise of what you have tried, or from this list?

1. Fastcgi Daemon - Yandex's opensource framework for design highload
   FastCGI applications on C + +
   https://github.com/golubtsov/Fastcgi-Daemon
2. FastCGI is simple because it is actually CGI with only a few
   extensions. http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/
3. a C + + class library for writing CGI applications
   http://www.gnu.org/software/cgicc/
4. a Native C\C++ Module for IIS 7.0
   http://www.iis.net/learn/develop/runtime-extensibility/develop-a-native-cc-module-for-iis
5. Apache API C++ Cookbook
   http://wolfgang.groogroo.com/apache-cplusplus/
6. C++/Delphi - Embedded WebServer/ISAPI with simply front-end's
   builder (html, css, extjs) http://unigui.com/demo

Comment: You totally missed the best one: http://www.webtoolkit.eu/.

Comment: @Flexo For back-end that's looks perfect! But how is it easy to create a front-end GUI in visual builder, and which of them (IDE) I need to use for this, Qt? Unfortunately there is not found the answer to this question. I only found how to write source code.